# How to reduce the size of an .eps file?

Tags: eps, epstool

I know that this issue is not LATEX, but I think that it´s usefull for me and for others, because .eps is very used with latex.

I have 15 .eps files of 4 MB, and I note that it´s a little heavy to the viewer and to the compile to PDF.

How could I reduce this size without lossing many quality.

I use imagemagick sometimes.

Here is an example file https://www.dropbox.com/s/7n9hlpszm7m10jc/p01.eps

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two reasons why `eps` files produced by Mathematica (such as `p01.eps` linked in your question) are often excessively large. The first is specific to Mathematica, but the second seems to be common to a few applications that generate postscript images.

1: Some methods for exporting images (such as right-clicking on the image) will include a large amount of data as comments, in case the file should be loaded back into Mathematica. Use the the [Export command](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html) to avoid this.

2: Mathematica shades regions in a truly absurd way, using a huge number of small polygons where a few larger ones would do instead. A utility called [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/polygone.htm) deals with this by merging shapes that share a common edge.

A version of your file `p01.eps` that has been processed by polygone 4 (and had the excess comments removed) is available [here](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/temp/p01_nc_r.eps) (409Kb).

**EDIT**

Prompted by @Bernard's answer, I should point out that the best reduction is usually achieved by converting to `pdf` after processing with polygone. Converting the file produced by polygone using `epstopdf` results in a 123Kb image. Not bad when starting from 4.6Mb.

**EDIT 03/07/2014**

Version 4 of [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/polygone.htm) is now available.

Comment: Could you include a sentence at the beginning to explain why you are talking about Mathematica when the question didn't mention it? I realise you must have looked at the code but it may confuse people who don't know, for example, that `.eps` is a generic format into thinking that it is Mathematica-specific. (Certainly hope it isn't specific anyhow or I'm certainly deluded in thinking I've produced some myself!)

Comment: @cfr --- good point. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: :-) @IanThompson , in despite of Ian, I think that Ian have detected thta the graph was created with Mathematica, and I´m very gratefull for your comments. Please if youi edit, don´t delete the explanations about MAtheamtica.

Comment: @IanThompson  What I finally do is view eps with XnView, SaveAS JPG, and then convert to EPS with imagemagick to get a an eps of 550Kb instead the original 4MB (created and saved, as you detected ;-), with Mathematica). I can´t fin the option Export that you mentioned

Comment: @MikaIke But then it's not scalable anymore! By converting it to any raster image type you loose it.

Comment: @MikaIke --- If you convert to JPG you will definitely lose quality; JPG is a bitmap format. You should be able to find the Export command in the Mathematica manual (note that it is a command, not an option to be chosen from a menu).

Comment: @Manuel Thanl you very much, in this case It´s not important!. Its to put 15 images in a A4 page.

Comment: Hi, I just know the utility polygone. However, I don't know how to run it on my Macbook. May you kindly explain how to use the program?

Comment: @JohnZHANG --- Do you have a Fortran compiler installed?

Answer (score 2):

You also can convert it to `.pdf` with `Ghostscript` and its Windows interface `GsView`. You'll still have a vector format, and as .pdf is more or less a compressed .ps format, you'll get a rather considerable size reduction — in the case of your file and  600dpi resolution, it is only 660 Kb. Unfortunately I don't know where I could upload the resulting file.

Comment: Yes usually I do it, but in this case, with psmatrix only appears a column of the psmatrix. A few weeks later I ´ll back to this issue.