# How to reducing EPS file size for document?

Tags: epstopdf, file-size

I have eps files of 10-15 MB that i have generated from matlab. These figures are basically data plots and because of that file sizes are so high.

When i am using these files for pdf then output pdf file is taking too much time to load because of those eps figures. So is there any way so that i can reduce my file size.
Please help me out.

Regards

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: This isn't really a tex question. You could probably use some general options to ghostscript (or a wrapper such as convert or epstopdf) to reduce the file size, but probably you will get best results by regenerating the images from matlab, there you can sample the data and so reduce the size in a way that is aware of the semantics of the plot.

Comment: Programs like Matlab or Mathematica produce inefficient eps code. Try exporting to jpg or pdf.

Comment: There is a utility called [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/index.htm) that can drastically reduce the size of `eps` graphics in some cases. [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185030/2417) might help.

Answer (score 1):

It is much faster to with `.pdf` images instead. I have some very complex figures which take forever to compile. When I generate the `.pdf` images (note that the figures are usually not frequently modified) and work with `pdflatex`, the compilation is almost immediate.